# Serial to File - No append

Tags: io-redirection, serial-port

I have an Arduino sending data over a serial port to my Ubuntu PC.  This is working as I can open a serial monitor on the PC and view the data. The arduino sends one line of data every 2 seconds.  I want to redirect the output to a text file on the PC.  I tried:

```
(stty raw; cat > /home/me/received.txt) < /dev/ttyUSB2
```

It works but it appends each line received to the file.  I want it to over write the file each time.  In other words, the file should only ever have one line of data in it which would be the newest received.

I thought the < vs << would take care of that but obviously I am missing something.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: `<` means redirect input from a file (by name) and `<<` means from the current script/stdin. You presumably mean `>` versus `>>` which redirect output to the beginning of a file (truncate) or the end (append) _when the process is started_, but while the process runs it writes sequentially.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was incorrectly thinking.  Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
(stty raw; while IFS= read -R line; do
printf '%s\n' "$line" > /home/me/received.txt; done) < /dev/ttyUSB2
```

Comment: Thanks.  It didn't like the capital R.  Changed it to lower case and works perfectly.  Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to slightly abuse awk:

```
( stty raw; awk -v f="outfile" '{print >f; close(f)}' )<tty
```